# Perl hash of arrays clarification

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I need clarification on how hash of arrays works. I'm trying to add one element array to a hash and then retrieve it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use diagnostics;

my %h;
my $key = "a";
my $val = "x";

push @{ $h{$key} }, $val;
print "1: " . $h{$key} . "\n";
print "2: " . $h{$key}[0] . "\n";

my @arr = $h{$key};
print "3: " . $arr[0] . "\n";
```

This prints out:

```
1: ARRAY(0x8ffe98)
2: x
3: ARRAY(0x8ffe98)
```

I'm wondering what is the difference between line 2 and line 3, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`my @arr = $h{$key};` is creating an array of a single element - the array-ref, just as if it had been written as `my @arr = ( $h{$key} );`. That is, the expression does *not* otherwise [dereference the array-ref](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/perl-array-reference-examples/).

Thus `$arr[0]` (#3) evaluates to the same value as `$h{$key}` (#1) and not `$h{$key}[0]` (#2).

Instead, consider this form with a dereference where the resulting list is assigned to the array variable:

```
my @arr = @{ $h{$key} };
```

(Now `$arr[0]` will be the same as `$h{key}[0]`.)

Comment: Ah, great. So I could also do my $ar = $h{$key}; print @$ar[0]; ?

Comment: @mehturt You'd likely want to use: `my $ar = $h{$key}; print $ar->[0];` (no @, and simple "reference" into an index of the array-ref), or if you did want the entire list `print @$ar;`. Remember that `$ar[i]` is going to be looking for `@ar`.

Comment: This does not work for me, however @$ar[0] does. I want to print the 1st element of the array, which should be the $val.

Answer (score 1):

You're being slightly confused by this assignment, since you're assigning the array reference to an array:

```
my @arr = $h{$key};
print "3: " . $arr[0] . "\n";
```

The above assignment is equivalent to:

```
my ($ref) = $h{$key};
print "3: " . $ref . "\n";
```

Which as you can tell visually, is the same as your print #1.

If you'd like to assign the values of your reference to your new array, you will have to dereference it:

```
my @arr = @{$h{$key}};
```

However, modifications to your new array `@arr` will not effect your original data structure.

Answer (score 1):

The question is already answered, but for help you should to use some data-dumping utility, what helps visualise what happens. For example [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data%3a%3aDumper) or [Data::Printer](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data%3a%3aPrinter) .

e.g. with Data::Printer

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use diagnostics;
use DDP;

my %h;
my $key = "a";
my $val = "x";

p %h;
push @{ $h{$key} }, $val;
p %h;

my @arr = $h{$key};
p @arr;
```

prints:

```
{}

{
    a   [
        [0] "x"
    ]
}

[
    [0] [
        [0] "x"
    ]
]
```

with Data::Dumper

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use diagnostics;
use Data::Dumper;

my %h;
my $key = "a";
my $val = "x";

print Dumper \%h;
push @{ $h{$key} }, $val;
print Dumper \%h;

my @arr = $h{$key};
print Dumper \@arr;
```

prints similar output

```
$VAR1 = {};
$VAR1 = {
          'a' => [
                   'x'
                 ]
        };
$VAR1 = [
          [
            'x'
          ]
        ];
```

Comment: btw, [`Data::Dump`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dump) is usually the easiest to read dumper

Comment: @amon, for me the output from `dd` is for more complex structires not as clear. But ofc - this is a personal preference ;)